# rearranging file into three columns

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to compare the list of installed packages on a couple of computers running CentOS 6.4.  The output of `yum list installed` is not ordered nicely into three columns, e.g.:

```
ImageMagick.x86_64      6.5.4.7-6.el6_2 @base     
MAKEDEV.x86_64          3.24-6.el6      @anaconda-CentOS-201303020151.x86_64/6.4
ModemManager.x86_64     0.4.0-3.git20100628.el6
                                        @anaconda-CentOS-201303020151.x86_64/6.4
NetworkManager.x86_64   1:0.8.1-43.el6  @anaconda-CentOS-201303020151.x86_64/6.4
NetworkManager-glib.x86_64
                        1:0.8.1-43.el6  @anaconda-CentOS-201303020151.x86_64/6.4
```

Long lines are wrapped to fit into 80 columns, which means that if I `sort` this file the information for some packages will be scrambled..  **Is there a simple awk command to take this output and print three fields per line?**

I have tried searching for similar examples, but I only find cases where people split one long line into columns.

Comment: It is not; see my example lines (lines 3-4 and 6-7).  Each package has three fields associated with it, and if the line would be longer than 80 characters with all three fields the line is split.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If each *column* is guaranteed not to contain spaces then this approach might do the trick:

```
$ yum list installed | xargs -n3 | column -t
ImageMagick.x86_64          6.5.4.7-6.el6_2          @base
MAKEDEV.x86_64              3.24-6.el6               @anaconda-CentOS-201303020151.x86_64/6.4
ModemManager.x86_64         0.4.0-3.git20100628.el6  @anaconda-CentOS-201303020151.x86_64/6.4
NetworkManager.x86_64       1:0.8.1-43.el6           @anaconda-CentOS-201303020151.x86_64/6.4
NetworkManager-glib.x86_64  1:0.8.1-43.el6           @anaconda-CentOS-201303020151.x86_64/6.4
```

Comment: Better than awk!  I know there are no spaces in each field, so this works perfectly.

Comment: This only works if the header lines output by _yum list installed_ at the start has a mutiple of 3 words!!! Mine does not. One hack is to strip off the first two lines `… | tail -n +2 | …`